# How to generate a .pfx file from a .cer file?

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate, keystore, pfx, mmc

I've only the .cer file now i want to convert it to .pfx file. But when i tried to convert via openssl it is asking for private key file? Is it necessary to have a private key file to generate a .pfx file? if not then could you please suggest the open ssl command to accomplish this.
Thanks 
Sushma.

Comment: A PFX file is a container for both private and public key. So you cannot make one with any of those keys. CER contains only your public key. What are you accomplishing by your actions?

Comment: ThanksRaj for the clarifications, actually i got the .cer file from the client and my requirement is to create the .pfx file, the client had not provided the private key file.