# How to get .pfx file from .cer and .key?

Tags: windows, security, ssl, ssl-certificate

Before questioning here. I've searched a lot about my problem. And problem is still exists. Below is the references of posts, which I've already read.

[How to create .pfx file from certificate and private key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6307886/how-to-create-pfx-file-from-certificate-and-private-key)

[Convert a CERT/PEM certificate to a PFX certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/808669/convert-a-cert-pem-certificate-to-a-pfx-certificate)

[How to get .pem file from .key and .crt files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/991758/how-to-get-pem-file-from-key-and-crt-files)

[How to generate a .pfx file from a .cer file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29490922/how-to-generate-a-pfx-file-from-a-cer-file)

**Overview**

I'm working on:

> Windows 10 64bit
>
> IIS (Version 10.0.16299.15)
>
> I've installed Win32 OpenSSL v1.1.0g

These are the files that I have available:

- server.cer
- server.key

**What I've tried?**

I have also tried various things from trawling through posts but my lack of experience in this area is really impeding my efforts.

Below commands I have tried in Terminal to create my `server.key` and `server.cer` file.

```
set RANDFILE=c:\certificate\.md

set OPENSSL_CONF=c:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin\openssl.cfg

c:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin\openssl.exe genrsa -out server.key 2048`

c:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin\openssl.exe req -new -key server.key -out server.cer -config C:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin\openssl.cfg

c:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin\openssl.exe pkcs12 -export -in server.cer -inkey server.key -out server.pfx
```

**Output**
[image]

**Error:** unable to load certificates

**What I want?**

How to create .pfx file from certificate and private key? Let me know what I'm doing wrong in my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `req` command creates a certificate *request* by default, not a certificate. If you add the `-x509` argument, it will self-sign the request using the provided key, and output a certificate instead. You should then be able to create the .pfx successfully.

Comment: Where I add `-x509` argument in `c:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin\openssl.exe req -new -key server.key -out server.cer -config C:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin\openssl.cfg`

Comment: Found my answer: By running this command `req -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout server.key -days 365 -out server.cer` and after that I run `pkcs12 -export -in server.cer -inkey server.key -out server.pfx` `.pfx` file generated successfully. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 11):

Although, the question is answered, I would like to add a simpler solution.

There is no need to use any 3rd party tools (including OpenSSL) on Windows. You can use built-in `certutil.exe` tool. Place both files in the same folder and give the same name to files (e.g. `server.cer` and `server.key`) and run the following command:

```
certutil -mergepfx path\server.cer
```

Certutil will expect to find a key file in the same folder with `.key` file extension.

Comment: This still works as of Jan 2022 in PowerShell on Windows 11 and it is by far the easiest solution.  You do need to specify the output file though: certutil -mergefx .\server.cer server.pfx