# C# Import private key to X509Certificate2

Tags: c#, rest, cryptography, ssl-certificate

In C#, I need to load a `X509Certificate2` with an encrypted private key, imported from a .key file. The `RSACryptoServiceProvider` does not take any arguments to import such key, and my research has not provided any success.

I have tried [this link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/162194/Certificates-to-DB-and-Back).

The certificate is used to retrieve JSON from a REST API.

Comment: .NET doesn't support PKCS#1 or PKCS#8 keys (though, CryptoAPI does). You need to convert your certificate and key to PKCS#12 file by using certitil tool: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48473273/3997611 and then use `X509Certificaye2(string, SecureString` constructor: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms148419(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Crypt32 Thanks! Solved the problem!